# Crash on device Expo

Tags: ios, expo

I get the following crash on device when running from ipa, build with Expo. Any ideas?

```
{"app_name":"xxxxxxx","timestamp":"2019-12-31 07:02:30.19 -0800","app_version":"1.0.0","slice_uuid":"xxxxxxxx","adam_id":xxxxxx,"build_version":"1","bundleID":"xxxxxxx","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.3 (17C54)","incident_id":"xxxxxxx","name":"xxxxxxx"}
Incident Identifier: xxxxxxxx
CrashReporter Key:   xxxxxxx
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             xxxxxxxx [4049]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx.app/xxxxxxxxx
Identifier:          xxxxxxxx
Version:             1 (1.0.0)
AppStoreTools:       11C29
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           xxxxxx [1556]


Date/Time:           2019-12-31 07:02:30.0470 -0800
Launch Time:         2019-12-31 07:02:29.8735 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.3 (17C54)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1a6478a48 __exceptionPreprocess + 220
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a619ffa4 objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1a637d0ec -[NSException raise] + 11
3   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx               0x10609c16c GADApplicationVerifyPublisherInitializedAnalyticsCorrectly + 21250412 (GADAnalytics.m:257)
4   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx            0x10604cc58 -[GADApplication runMainThreadEarlyActivities] + 20925528 (GADApplication.m:282)
```

Using AdMod and Firebase SDKs. app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "xxx",
    "slug": "xxx",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "35.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],

    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "xxxx",
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-1234~5678..."
      },
      "supportsTablet": false
    },
...
}
```

GADApplicationIdentifier is added to info.plist as well

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add GADApplicationIndentifier inside "ios" : {} like this:

```
  "ios" : {
      ....
      "infoPlist":  {
         "GADApplicationIdentifier": "ca-app-pub-4...."
       }

  }
```

also double check that your App Id is correct